# "Mainstream" as an adjective?

Tags: traducción

A dictionary gave me "corriente principal" for "mainstream" as a noun.  But "principal" is not working very well for me as a translation of "mainstream," when used as an adjective.

The context has to do with performance arts.

Comment: I would suggest "convencional", but if you give some context we can probably come with a better term. What is the complete sentence, context or noun you want to use "mainstream" with?

Comment: @Diego - added some context.

Comment: A source of ideas: [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/mainstream.html) - providing real-life translations, some of which may be useful.

Comment: @pablodf76 - great resource, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Mainstream` has the meaning of "widely used or accepted": the common current thought of the majority or the things that are currently popular. It is the "**conventional ideas**".

In Spanish this could be translated as `convencional`.

> Esa nueva corriente de pensamiento no es nada *convencional*
>
> Las obras de teatro de ese director son siempre muy *convencionales*. Yo prefiero otros más transgresores.

Other possible translations would be

- lo normal
- lo establecido"
- la corriente de pensamiento *establecida / dominante / mayoritaria / principal*